# Why is shared_ptr returning an empty list?

Tags: c++, xerces-c

I am working with Xerces-c (version 3.2) and I have this function that wraps around the `XMLString::transcode` method.

```
XMLCh* class_name::transcode(const std::string text) {
  auto returned = std::shared_ptr<XMLCh>(XMLString::transcode(text.c_str()), class_name::releaseXMLCh);
  return returned.get();
}
```

(`XMLCh` is a `char16_t`)

The point of this is to have a shared pointer that will call `releaseXMLCh()` when it is no longer needed. Here is the implementation of `releaseXMLCh()`:

```
void class_name::releaseXMLCh(XMLCh* text) {
  XMLString::release(&text);
}
```

According to the Xerces-c documentation, `XMLString::release` needs to be called after calling `XMLString::transcode` to avoid a memory leak.

However, this function only ever returns `""`, regardless of what the input string is. I suspect that I am doing something wrong with the `shared_ptr`, as calling `XML::transcode` on its own works perfectly fine.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about it:

- you create a local `std::shared_ptr`.
- You get the (raw) pointer to the internal object.
- The local `std::shared_ptr` goes out of scope and is destructed.

How many `std::shared_ptr`s will there be pointing to the internal object?

None. So it's also destructed. Thus, this will not work this way.

You are returning a pointer to a destroyed object, which causes Undefined Behavior.

You need a persisting smart pointer object (could likely even be a `unique_ptr`) or just use the old-fashioned `new`-`delete`.

Comment: You are very much correct, and that was part of the problem, but I think it's not the only problem. I will post an update soon. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: @pscarpati please. only one problem per question. Don't edit new problems into existing questions (as per Stack Overflow rules) since that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Fair point, thanks for pointing it out